# How to make 2 different links have 2 different CSS properties?

Tags: html, css

First off sorry about the title, I have no idea how to word it. Any suggestions will be great.

With my website my title bar at the top is a "a href" so I have put in my CSS

```
a:link {text-decoration:none;}    /* unvisited link */
a:visited {text-decoration:none;} /* visited link */
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */

a:link {color:black;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:black;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:white;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:white;}  /* selected link */
```

I have now added another "a href" in a different place and obviously it has the same properties as the title. I was wondering if I could edit the two separately? Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/

And again, Sorry for the title!! and thanks in advance.

Comment: Add classes to those elements and define them in CSS

Comment: Just add a class to the links in the header.

Answer (score 3):

Add a 'class' or an 'id' attribute to the `<a>` tag.

Your html:

```
<a class="firstStyle" href="./">First link</a>
<a class="secondStyle" href="./">Second link</a>
```

Your css:

```
.firstStyle {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.secondStyle{
    color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a supplement to abrunet's answer to illustrate how to individually style the anchor types while using class names.

```
a.secondStyle:link {
    color:black;
}
a.secondStyle:hover {
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use pesudo selector in css and select just your title or use id and class to each  tags